# How do I take a string and separate into its individual components? in this case, each component will have 2 characters

Tags: python, integer

How do I take a string like: 45 78 87 45 29 12 and turn that into each respect digits, like "4,5", "7,8", "8,7", "4,5", "2,9", "1,2"? Thanks.

Should I use something like:

```
n = (45,78,87,45,29,12)
x= [int(y) for y in str(n)]
```

Comment: Is it a string or a tuple?  You said both.  Please show actual code so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 0):

The question is ambiguous. However, assuming the required output is as shown in the question and that the input is a string of numbers then:

```
s = "45 78 87 45 29 12"

def f(s):
    for t in s.split():
        yield '"' + ",".join(t) + '"'

print(", ".join(f(s)))
```

**Output:**

```
"4,5", "7,8", "8,7", "4,5", "2,9", "1,2"
```